# Set icon to custom QFontDialog

Tags: c++, qt

I created my own font dialog from QFontDialog (new SLOT added). After that, I can't set icon (*.png) to my new font dialog (with func. setWindowIcon). If I use setWindowIcon to default QFontDialog - everything is OK. So, how to set icon to my new font dialog?

FontDialog.h

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

class FontDialog: public QFontDialog {
    public:
        FontDialog();
        ~FontDialog();
    public slots:
        void someSlot(void);
};
```

FontDialog.cpp

```
#include "FontDialog.h"

FontDialog::FontDialog() {
}

FontDialog::~FontDialog() {
}

void someSlot(void) {
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "FontDialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    FontDialog *fontDialog = new FontDialog();
    fontDialog->setWindowIcon(QIcon(".//icon.png")); // !!!NOT WORKING!!! for custom QFontDialog
    fontDialog->show(); 

    app.exec();
}
```

I'm using Qt 4.8.5 with Qt Designer 2.7.1 environment.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Posting the code for your QFontDialog subclass would make it much easier to see any errors that might be causing your problem.

Comment: Also, which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Are you sure the icon file path is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works under Qt 4.8.4 on both OS X and Windows 7. It also works on 5.1.1 on Windows, but not on OS X :(

```
#include <QFontDialog>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPainter>

class Dialog : public QFontDialog {
public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0) : QFontDialog(parent) {}
    Dialog(const QFont & initial, QWidget *parent = 0) : QFontDialog(initial, parent) {}
};

QIcon myIcon(const QColor & color)
{
    QIcon icon;
    QPixmap pm(128, 128);
    pm.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter p(&pm);
    p.translate(64, 64);
    p.scale(50, 50);
    p.setBrush(color);
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::lightGray, 0.1));
    p.drawEllipse(-1, -1, 2, 2);
    icon.addPixmap(pm);
    return icon;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setWindowIcon(myIcon(Qt::red));
    Dialog d;
    d.setWindowIcon(myIcon(Qt::blue));
    d.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. The problem was in contructors inside FontDialog class. Thanks for solve!